# How do I have different footers for the left and right pages on Apple Pages?

Tags: pages

I need to have different footers for left and right pages in Apple Pages to make a sort of book layout in which the page number is close to the outer page. How is this achieved?

Comment: Duplicate of https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/276611/apple-pages-use-a-different-header-for-odd-an-even-pages

Answer (score 1):

Facing pages/mirrored pages is not possible in Apple Pages v5.x. The last version of Pages that supported facing/mirrored pages is v4.x (iWork '09). If you have access to a copy of Pages v4.x, v5 can save in that format so you can use the file in '09. Otherwise you would need to use an alternative product, such as Microsoft Office, that supports facing pages.

Answer (score 1):

Facing Pages has now been restored to Pages V8+ (not sure when it returned), but to access it you must be in a 'facing pages' view. If you normally work in single page view, you will NEVER see the option.

Simply turn on facing pages,
Go to document layout ->
    Click Facing Pages.

Your view will now be left and right pages.
Now turn on headers and footers

Go to Section -> click left and right pages are different

The bonus, here is that the inside and outside margins are also mirrored.

Yay - Thanks for returning this functionality