# Apple Pages: Use a different header for odd an even pages

Tags: pages

In Apple Pages, is it possible to use a different header for odd and even pages?

I have searched around and found [this guide](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/302641?start=0&tstart=0), but I think it's for the old version of Pages (as it is from 2006 and have the interfaces buttons mentioned don't exist).

There are also guides on how to use different headers for [different sections](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h-vfejeYMfo), but that is different from odd and even pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2021 here, and yes, it is possible (again) with Pages (v. 11.1).

You can set the document to have a double page layout:

- select document pane in the top right
- under *document*, find the options for the margins of the document
- activate double page checkbox

Now you can set different headers for even / odd pages (most useful for pagination at the left / right respectively):

- again, make sure you selected the document pane (top right)
- under *section*, find the options for the header and footer
- activate the checkbox for different left/right layout.

PS: if any of my translations from my german version of Pages are a bit off, I am very sorry.

Answer (score 3):

This is currently not possible with Pages, as it was with Pages '09.

If you need this functionality, you can still use Pages '09 if you have it, but opening a document from Pages '09 with different headers for odd and even pages will cause such headers to be removed (and a warning thrown in Document Warnings).

You can provide feedback to Apple here:

- http://www.apple.com/feedback/pages.html